# 2023 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

[Moderator election #1](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/election/1) on Robotics Stack Exchange has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Chuck]

[image: Tully]

[image: Ben]

They will be joining [the moderator team](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking Mark Booth, who has served as a pro-tem moderator of the site until now, ever since it entered public beta way back in 2012:

[image: Mark Booth]

Without the dedication and contributions of all of the pro-tem mods (including Mark Booth, Ben, and previously Chuck) this site would not be where it is today. Thanks to them for their commitment to the site!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/election/1) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5810811183300608).

Comment: Thanks, it was an honour to serve.

Comment: Congrats to Ben, Chuck and Tully... and my thanks to Mark for his contribution and support during my tenure as a Pro-Tem moderator.